# Show all wp_get_post_terms slugs

Tags: slug, terms

I am using the following code to display my custom taxonomy slugs. However it is only displaying the first category and not all the related categories. I know this is fairly simple and is to do with [0] but I can't figure out how to change it.

```
$getslugid = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'opd_taggallery' ); 
$getslug = $getslugid [0]->slug;
echo $getslug;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a PHP question, but the solution is simple - you need to use a [`foreach`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)-loop on `$getslug`, because you just echo the slug of the first taxonomy.

The function `wp_get_post_terms()` does not return a single object, but an array of objects. You are right with the `[0]`, this indicates that you are checking the first entry of said array.

Your function should look something like this:

```
$getslugid = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'opd_taggallery' ); 
foreach( $getslugid as $thisslug ) {

    echo $thisslug->slug . ' '; // Added a space between the slugs with . ' '

}
```

Answer (score 6):

The WordPres Core function [`wp_list_pluck()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) should make this fairly easy.

```
$getslugid = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'opd_taggallery' ); 
$slugs = implode(', ',wp_list_pluck($getslugid,'slug'));
echo $slugs;
```

Comment: +1, did not even know about this function. As it also uses the foreach (talking performance), I still prefer my solution, as I have fine control and could use multiple fields of the object.

Comment: Yes, performance wise... probably not much difference. It is just a convenient shortcut if you only need one value.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Didn't know about `wp_list_pluck()`, thank you.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Same. Haven't heard about this function `wp_list_pluck`. Life saving :)

Answer (score 1):

In newer WordPress versions it is possible to directly query only the taxonomy slugs. I think this came with the introduction of the [WP_Term_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/) class in WP version 4.6.0.

```
$slugs = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'opd_taggallery', array( 
    'fields' => 'id=>slug',
) );
echo implode( " ", $slugs );
```